# Grouping by an ID, to find if there are variations in another column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have a spreadsheet with products listed. There is a product ID which represents different colors and sizes of the product. There is also a column for price.

I want to ensure that all the products with the same ID have the same price and there is no variation.

How do I group all cells with the same ID, and then run a check to ensure all those IDss have the same value in the price column?

I would prefer not to use VBA, if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Given this example spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet containing three columns with headings Product ID, Price, and Valid]

1. Sort by Product ID
2. Enter this formula into C1: `=OR(A2<>A1,B2=B1)`
3. Drag the formula down to C8
4. All the items with `FALSE` indicate values where the Product ID matches the Product ID above but the price doesn't match the price above.

The formula returns `TRUE` if either the Product ID of the current row is different than the Product ID of the row above (which means the prices don't need to match) **or** the price of the current row is the same as the price of the previous row (if the prices match, it can't be invalid). Otherwise, it returns `FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the size of your dataset and how often you want to do this, you might manage to do this manually by using Excel's "Filter" capability. This is a basic solution as I am not sure of your needs or experience:

- Click anywhere in your dataset
- Under the "Data" tab, click Filter. Your column names should have a dropdown button on them.
- Click the dropdown button on your ID field, and only select the ID you want to evaluate.
- Click the dropdown button on your price field, if there are any different values showing then they are not all the same.